# Python 2.7 format string padding with more than one char

Tags: python, string, string-formatting

## The Problem

I've been able to pad a string with asterisk, however I'd like to see if it is possible to pad it with an asterisk and a space.

## Example Output

What I've been able to get

`****************************Hello World***************************`

... trying to get

`* * * * * * * * * * * * * * Hello World* * * * * * * * * * * * * *`

## Attempts

Naively I tried passing a `" *"` to the fill parameter of the format specs. This returned with an error:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 17, in <module>
    ret_string = '*{:{f}^{n}}'.format(string, f=filler, n=line_len)
ValueError: Invalid conversion specification`

Then I tried using an escape character, `"\s*"`, which yielded the same result. Finally I revisited the documentation [6.1.3.1. Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) and see the input spec appears to be limited to a character and not open to strings. Is there a way around this? I thought of making a sort of compound reference ie `{{char1}{char2}}` but that doesn't seemed to have worked either.

Thoughts?

## The Code

```
import fileinput

string     = "Hello World"
ret_string = ""
line_len   = 65
filler    = " *"


for inputstring in fileinput.input():
    string = inputstring.strip(" \n")

ret_string = '{:{f}^{n}}'.format(string, f=filler, n=line_len)
print(ret_string)
```

Comment: I am pretty sure you can't do this with ``str.format``.

Comment: A somewhat fragile workaround could be based upon `s.replace("**", "* ")`...

Comment: @moooeeeep ultimately I went with your suggestion as I was only using this to quickly clean up code in another language. I came back and tried Martin Evans solution and it worked fine. Simplest answer I think. Thanks for all the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following would work for two character fill patterns:

```
string = "Hello World"
length = 65
fill = "* "

output = string.center(length, '\x01').replace('\x01\x01', fill).replace('\x01', fill[0])
print(len(output), output)
```

Python has a `center()` function which will pad a string with a single character pad character. You could then replace runs of 2 with your fill pattern. This could result in a single character, thus a second replace is used for this eventuality.
It uses the character `\x01` as a character unlikely to be in `string`.

The length of `output` is printed to prove it is the correct length.

```
65 * * * * * * * * * * * * * *Hello World* * * * * * * * * * * * * *
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this small function to do what you want, but I don't thinl you can do it with `str.format`:

```
def multi_char_pad(s, f, n):
    to_pad = n - len(s)
    pre = to_pad // 2
    post = to_pad - pre
    f_len = len(f)
    pre_s = f * (pre // f_len) + f[:pre % f_len]
    post_s = f * (post // f_len) + f[:post % f_len]
    return pre_s + s + post_s
```

You can probably one line it, but I think it is so easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

```
padding = "".join(["* "]*10)
print(padding + "hello " + padding)
```